# Updating xml tag in python using lxml Etree

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

I'm trying to update a single tag in my xml file with another value. I'm using lxml module in python.

```
bplocation = os.getcwd()+"/apiproxy/proxies";

tree = lxml.etree.parse(bplocation+'/default.xml');
root = tree.getroot();
update = lxml.etree.SubElement(root, "BasePath");
update.text = "new basepath";
root.SubElement('BasePath',update);

pretty = lxml.etree.tostring(root, encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True);

f = open("test.xml", "w")
f.write(pretty)
f.close()
```

I'm getting AttributeError: 'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'SubElement' error.
I just need the  tag updated in xml.
Below is the xml.

```
 <ProxyEndpoint name="default">
  <HTTPProxyConnection>
    <BasePath>/v2/test</BasePath>
    <VirtualHost>https_vhost_sslrouter</VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost>secure</VirtualHost>
  </HTTPProxyConnection>
 </ProxyEndpoint>
```

Comment: What is `root.SubElement('BasePath',update)` meant to do?

Comment: You don't need semicolons at the ends of lines

Comment: `'lxml.etree._Element' object has no attribute 'SubElement'` means you do `something_of_type__Element.SubElement`. In this case this probably means the line `root.SubElement('BasePath',update)` (next time please mark which line throws the error...) which is kinda... useless and wrong

Comment: yes root.SubElement is throwing the error. removing this line prints the entire file but my update doesn't happen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SubElement()` (a function in the `lxml.etree` module) creates a new element, but that is not necessary.

Just get a reference to the existing `<BasePath>` element and update its text content.

```
from lxml import etree
 
tree = etree.parse("default.xml")
 
update = tree.find("//BasePath")
update.text = "new basepath"
 
pretty = etree.tostring(tree, encoding="unicode", pretty_print=True)
print(pretty)
```

Output:

```
<ProxyEndpoint name="default">
  <HTTPProxyConnection>
    <BasePath>new basepath</BasePath>
    <VirtualHost>https_vhost_sslrouter</VirtualHost>
    <VirtualHost>secure</VirtualHost>
  </HTTPProxyConnection>
</ProxyEndpoint>
```